# why does grid search cross validation give some value of mean square error for different values of c, gamma, epsilon in support vector machine?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, svm

I am using `libsvm` in `matlab` for time series prediction using support vector machine. when i use grid search cross validation to select paramaters C , GAMMA & EPSILON The value of cross validation mean square error is coming same for different values of these parameters so, by default the best parameters C, GAMMA & EPSILON are the first values in the given range of parameters which is clearly not the case.

this is my code can you please suggest best parameter ranges (c, gamma,and Epsilon)

```
% TRAINING DATASET 
SPECTR = csvread('train.csv'); % read a csv file 
trainlabels = SPECTR(:, 1); % labels from the 1st column 
trainfeatures = SPECTR(:, 2:end);  
trainfeatures_sparse = sparse(trainfeatures); % features must be in a sparse matrix 
libsvmwrite('SPECTRlibsvm.train', trainlabels, trainfeatures_sparse); 

% TESTING DATASET 
SPECTE = csvread('test.csv'); % read a csv file 
testlabels = SPECTE(:, 1); % labels from the 1st column 
testfeatures = SPECTE(:, 2:end);  
testfeatures_sparse = sparse(testfeatures); % features must be in a sparse matrix 
libsvmwrite('SPECTElibsvm.test', testlabels, testfeatures_sparse); 
idx1=[];

%GRID SEARCH
[C,gamma,eps] = meshgrid(2:0.1:4, -2:0.1:0, -9:0.1:-6); 
for j=1:numel(C)
    cmd = ['-s 3 -t 2 -v 5 -c ', num2str(2^C(j)), ' -g ', 
    num2str(2^gamma(j)), ' -p ', num2str(2^eps(j)),'-h' 0]; 
    mse(j) = svmtrain(trainlabels, trainfeatures, cmd);
    sprintf('-c %f -g %f -p %f',2^C(j), 2^gamma(j),2^eps(j));
end


[~,idx] = min(mse);
idx1=[idx1 idx];
mse_cv =mse(idx);
best_C = 2^C(idx);
best_gamma = 2^gamma(idx);
best_eps = 2^eps(idx);
```

Comment: Can you also provide some example output MSEs, i.e. are all of them equal? You can maybe try a much broader range with less number of cases (e.g. 1:10 for C instead of 2:0.1:4) and see if it's still the same. Also, why don't you test on the test set, and what does `svmtrain` return to you?